# pushing big files into Kafka topic through producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Files are uploading through client on server folder. it is continuously uploading files from different client using TUS API(File resumeabl upload) . size of files are from 5 mb to 100 mb. Now i want to push these files into Kafka producer asynchronously through java but not able to do so.  One option i tried with watch folder but not sure how it is effective in production. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered not writing them to Kafka itself? Maybe write the file to object storage and a pointer to it in  the Kafka message. Kafka is not generally suited to large files like 100MB.

Comment: "but not able to do so" is not very helpful... It's unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka imposes a limit on message size, so you won't be capable of putting anything larger than that. You can configure it at `max.message.bytes`, but it might have side effects (such as memory footprint of kafka server).

You also have other alternatives:

- chunking the message and making a smart consumer that would re-assemble the chunks on receiving them
- storing the data in external service (e.g. redis/something sql) and passing only a pointer to the external service

Some of the constraints related to these are documented in [this article](https://medium.com/workday-engineering/large-message-handling-with-kafka-chunking-vs-external-store-33b0fc4ccf14)